# two separate LAN over power line

Tags: networking, lan

I have two networks with two different external IP address, of course I have two routers where separate PCs are connected.

My question is if is possible to run with the adapter like DHP-342 or DHP 200 this two
LANs over power without conflict?

Answer (score 1):

If both networks have routers running DHCP, you most likely will have problems regardless of the method you use to link them (powerline, ethernet cable, wireless).

Comment: If you turn one's DHCP off, doesn't that router become more like a smart switch?